# Как получить MethodInfo для закрытого (private) нестатического метода?

Tags: c#, .net

Как в экземпляре класса получить `MethodInfo` для одного из его методов?

```
public class LambdaOptimizer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public LambdaOptimizer(LambdaExpression lambda, MethodInfo method)
    {
        var method = method;
        var newMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod("newF", BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    }

    private object newF(params object[] args)
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: а что вам нужно?

Comment: и чем вас не устраивает `System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()`?

Comment: `GetType().GetMethod()`

Comment: Тем, что он возвращает его для текущего метода, т.е. во время выполнения @mononax

Comment: а чем вас не устроило предложение @АндрейNOP ?

Comment: @Monomax почему вы решили, что оно не устроило топикастера? Оно же не оформлено как ответ,  зеленую галку на него не поставишь

Comment: @PashaPash пытаюсь понять, найдено решение проблемы или нет, а поскольку в комментарии отсутствует запись, на то что автор нашел решение, вот я и спрашиваю.

Comment: @Mihail: 1) Вы пытались сделать с GetMethod? 2) Покажите ваш класс.

Comment: @VladD, пробовал, но он возвращает только в том случае, если метод статический и публичный. Пробовал флаги ставить, не получилось -- вернул null

Comment: @Mihail: У меня работало. Покажите ваш класс, я подберу флаги.

Comment: @VladD, обновил топик

Comment: @Mihail: Добавьте `BindingFlags.Instance`

Comment: `.GetMethod("newF", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)`

Comment: @Mihail, не отмечайте ответ галочкой если он вам не подходит :) Дополнил ответ, проверяйте.

Comment: @VladD Спасибо, заработало. Я по невнимательности вместо | писал & :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь одной из перегрузок [`Type.GetMethod()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.type.getmethod(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var methodInfo = GetType().GetMethod("MyMethod"); // подразумевается this.GetType()...
```

либо можно узнать тип на этапе компиляции (немного эффективнее), но придется явно указать класс:

```
var methodInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("MyMethod");
```

PS: ну и желательно вместо явной строковой константы `"MyMethod"` использовать конструкцию `nameof(MyMethod)`, которая определит название метода во время компиляции, а также автоматически отреагирует на рефакторинг переименования метода.

---

UPD после добавления кода в вопрос. Вам подойдет такой код:

```
var newMethod = GetType().GetMethod(nameof(newF),
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```